# Javascript image handling library

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I need to some extra functionalities to a website regarding image handling.

The user must be able to pane, zoom and rotate images on a image gallery.

Is there any free javascript library/framework that handles this actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/)

is a good one

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library
>   that should simplify your work with
>   vector graphics on the web. If you
>   want to create your own specific chart
>   or image crop and rotate widget, for
>   example, you can achieve it simply and
>   easily with this library.
>
> Raphaël uses the SVG W3C
>   Recommendation and VML as a base for
>   creating graphics. This means every
>   graphical object you create is also a
>   DOM object, so you can attach
>   JavaScript event handlers or modify
>   them later. Raphaël’s goal is to
>   provide an adapter that will make
>   drawing vector art compatible
>   cross-browser and easy.

[loupe.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666830/javascript-image-handling-library) has an excellent zoom functionality.

Comment: I went with your suggestion. pixastic does not support ie.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pixastic.com/ --> looks real nice, I am just curious about other opinions as this is an area I am new at.